# How to use params for user dashboard in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a question about the params:

How to filter the display of each user in my controller.

in my model

user.rb:
`has_many: questions`

question.rb
`belongs_to: user`

controller:

`   skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [ :new ]
    before_action :find_question, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

```
def index
    @questions = Questions.all
end

private

def find_question
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
end`
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'filter the display of each user in my controller.' ? Could you provide an example of what you're trying to do ?

Comment: I just want to have for each user logged in their individual responses

Comment: I'm assuming people are logging in to your site?  Are you using devise or did you roll your own authentication?  You can use the "current_user" method to get the right person and then display all the related records easily if using devise or most standard custom auth approaches.

Comment: Yes they are log, i use devise and i use current_user

Comment: can you clear what exactly you want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ok

My solution is realy simple....

create users_controller with:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @questions = @user.questions
    end
end
```

and

users.html.erb with:

```
<% @questions.each do |question| %>
    bla,bla,bla,bla
<% end %>
```

Thanks for your time.